# Android Navigation Drawer - can the extension distance be set?

Tags: android

I've implemented the navigation drawer and it looks like it extends about 80% of the screen.

With the content that I'm showing, it looks too little extension distance on a phone, and on a 10" tablet it's too much.

Is it possible to customize the distance that the navigation drawer extends ?

EDIT: layout XML added

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <!-- Title Bar -->
            <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/title_background">

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/name_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />

                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/drawer_btn"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_background" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>


    <!-- Right drawer with transparent background that pulls out to left and contains a webview to show local content -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#00000000">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/funny_face"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/title_drawer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="30sp" 
                android:background="#000000"/>

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webview_drawer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the XML layout you are using for the drawer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawer extension distance can be changed programmatically by setting the drawer's layout_width

*NOTE:* by default, if the layout_width is set to `match_parent`, then you get the default behavior of 80% extension over the screen.

---

SAMPLE CODE TO SHOW HOW TO PROGRAMMATICALLY ADJUST THE DRAWER EXTENSION DISTANCE

**in XML layout :**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ui_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false" >

        <!-- STUFF GOES IN HERE FOR YOUR MAIN UI -->

    </FrameLayout>


    <!-- Drawer with black background that pulls out to left: see layout_gravity to change direction -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#000000">

        <!-- STUFF GOES IN HERE FOR YOUR DRAWER UI -->

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**In your activity :**

```
// class members
private LinearLayout mDrawer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layoutwithdrawer);

    mDrawer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    // dynamically adjust the layout width so that the drawer extends more or less (code below uses 95%)
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    DrawerLayout.LayoutParams params = (DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) mDrawer.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = (int) (width * 0.95f);
    mDrawer.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```